# Importing function from nested_directory/filename.py

Tags: python, import

I have following directory structure:

```
V1.0/
    module/
          answer_type/
                 __init__.py
                 worker.py
                 src/
                      __init__.py  
                      ans_type/
                           __init__.py
                           sent_process.py
          module_two/
          module_three/
```

I have put `__init__.py` file in directory so that it can be imported. But still it does not allow to import the class from inner most file.

`sent_process.py` looks like

```
from light_lizer.result_initiator import ResultInitiator
import re
import sys
import gearman
import sys,json

class QueryPylinkAnsTypeDetector(GearManOverride):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super(QueryAnsTypeDetector, self).__init__(config)
        self.init_log()

    def init_log(self):
        print "__init_log"
        self.abs_path = os.path.abspath(__file__).replace(os.getcwd(),'').replace('/','-').replace('.py','').replace('.','_')
        self.log_set_obj = LogSetting(type(self).__name__)
        self.logger = self.log_set_obj.logger

    def preProcessLink(self, link):
    new_link = link[-2:]
        return new_link


    def processSentenceSingle(self, read_str):
        post_script_link_list = []
    linkage[0] = 'xyz'
    post_script_link_list = self.preProcessLink(linkage[0])
        return result
```

in `worker.py` I am trying to import function from `sent_process.py`

```
from src.ans_type.sent_process import QueryPylinkAnsTypeDetector as PylinkProcess
```

gives error: `from src.answer_type.pylink_process import QueryPylinkAnsTypeDetector
ImportError: No module named src.ans_type.sent_process`

Can someone please suggest what is wrong here?

**Update:**

Being in `V1.0` directory, I am executing worker in this way:

```
python - m module/answer_type/worker
```

Comment: You don't have an `__init__.py` in `/ans_type`...

Comment: @jonrsharpe: updated, added `init` file in `/ans_type` dir and tested, but still same error

Comment: your structure looks legit, which means that you are probably missing something ( file permissions, execution path...). When you call: python worker.py do you have the same error or is it only when you import the module elsewhere?

Comment: @SamyArous: permission i checked, there's no  issue with that. I have issue with worker.py only while importing in this way. nowhere else

Comment: Can you give us exactly what is your import chain here? I can see that worker<-sent_process but what comes before worker?

Comment: @SamyArous: I updated the directory flow, and please also see `update` in question